# How to output hasMany related data?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I can't output related by hasMany data

Models:

```
App.Album = DS.Model.extend({
    title:              DS.attr('string'),
    index:              DS.attr('number'),
    preview:            DS.attr('string'),
    preview_uri:    DS.attr('string'),

    create_time:    DS.attr('date'),
    update_time:    DS.attr('date'),

    photos: DS.hasMany('photo'),
});

App.Photo = DS.Model.extend({
    file:                   DS.attr('string'),
    index:              DS.attr('number'),
    file_uri:           DS.attr('string'),

    update_time:    DS.attr('date'),
    create_time:    DS.attr('date'),

    albums: DS.hasMany('album')
});
```

Template:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="albums">
    {{#each}}
        <div><img {{bind-attr src=preview_uri}}></div>
        <div>{{id}}#{{title}}</div>

        {{#each photos}}
        <div style="margin-left: 40px;">
            <div><img {{bind-attr src=file_uri}}></div>
            <div>{{id}}</div>
        </div>
        {{/each}}
    {{/each}}
</script>
```

Albums json:

```
{
  "albums":[
    {
      "id":"1",
      "title":"album1",
      "preview":"filexx",
      "create_time":"2013-09-13 22:18:56",
      "update_time":"2013-09-13 22:40:57",
      "index":"0",
      "photo_ids":[
        "1"
      ],
      "preview_uri":"\/uploads\/fi\/le\/xx\/f.png"
    }
  ]
}
```

I'm using standart RESTAdapter. After transition it loads albums properly, and renders them, but without photos, what I'm doing wrong?

**It seems, that all similar questions related to older versions of ember-data, I'm using v1.0.0-beta.2**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe in beta 2 you would need to change `photo_ids` to `photos` unless you use a serializer that is compatible with ActiveModelSerializer (such as `DS.ActiveModelSerializer`). Not sure if that is the only issue though.